# Tuple and dendogram

Tags: c#, tuples

I am trying to build a dendogram using tuple and I have some issues like:

```
Tuple<Tuple<string, double>, double> t = new Tuple< new Tuple<string, double>(), double>();
```

The tuple inside is the leaf (name and distance) and the outside is the node with its distance.
How can I instantiate correctly this type of structure?

Comment: This is a situation where a custom class is way better...

Comment: Agreed with dig, but if you *do* use a `Tuple`, at least use a `Tuple<string, double, double>` instead, as they can have more than just 2 items in them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Tuple.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx) static helper method, and let the compiler help you with type inference.

```
 var t = Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("", 0.0d), 0.0d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner `new` and separately call the constructor of the inner `Tuple` as a parameter:

```
Tuple<Tuple<string, double>, double> t = new Tuple<Tuple<string, double>, double>(new Tuple<string, double>("", 0), 0);
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you need to pass all the properties values in the constructor